# Filesystem operations don't work from my PHP script; do I need to chmod something?

Tags: php, permissions, chmod

I am having some permissions problems with `mkdir` in PHP. I am trying to simply move some files around (and create a folder to put them in), but I am getting this error:

```
mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied in
```

On my old site, I had my folders set to 755 and things seemed to work fine. It *seems* like the only time I can get `mkdir` or related functions to work on this server is when folders have 777 as their mode.

Is the web browser considered "Others"? I don't feel like leaving my folders at 777 is a great idea, right?

Comment: good edit, Jim...didn't know how to put that correctly:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to create folders on your server that you can then write to from your web browser you may need to use at least 775.  Note that this isn't necessarily the case for creating files.  In fact, you probably don't want your files to be 777 at all.

You can also use bash commands within the php code if you would like to avoid having your server (aka www-data) create the directories but you'll still need to place the correct permissions on the folders to allow www-data to then write files to the directories.

Do check your ownerships.  The above is based on a folder being owned by some user and group owned by www-data.  You can also try to set the folder ownership to www-data but the permission would still be rwx for that particular user.

I hope that's not way to convoluted.

Commands that might help you find out who is running apache on your server:

```
#top
```

look for something like:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                          
20610 www-data  20   0 36772  10m 4380 S    4  0.1   0:04.03 apache2
```

or

```
#ps aux | grep "apache"
```

look for something like

```
www-data 26898  0.0  0.0  34248  4076 ?        S    17:59   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Comment: patrick...is www-data a common user? i haven't seen it yet. at the moment the user that "owns" the file is my plesk user..."johnnie"

Comment: ..and..i will be allowing people to upload photos etc on the site, so the web server will need to allow the browser to add/edit/etc

Comment: www-data is a common user on ubuntu and similar systems.  You might also recognize it as http or apache.  I don't know how much access you have to your server but you can try a couple of things to find out whose running apache.

try running "top" at the command line and then query a webpage on your server.  You'll probably see a line quickly go to the top that is labeled as a command:apache.  You can also check the /etc/group file to get an idea about the system users.  

Another thing you could try at the command line would be "ps aux | grep "apache".

Answer (score 1):

The web browser is not the object considered as "others", but rather the user that the web server is run as, for example `httpd` or `apache`.

A common method is to chown the files to set the user and/or group to the web server user, thereby allowing permissions such as 755.

Example:

`chown apache:apache ./example/`

Comment: Is something like this also possible when on a shared host when you uploaded a folder via an FTP client, and want PHP to write to it? If so, how would one detect what the user/group of the server is?

PS.: I'm aware of suPHP and such, but not all shared hosts offer this, I'm afraid.

Comment: okay...@enbuy...so say the web server is run under my Plesk user "johnnie". when i check the permissions etc, it says: user is johnnie, group is psacln. shouldn't that mean the browser should be cool? ...btw thanks for your time

Comment: @johnnietheblack: I'm too late :), seems you're set now

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be applicable, depending on the OS you are running the webserver on, you may have other security mechanisms that are interferring with what you are trying to do.  One glaring example (which befudled me for a time) is the SELinux security system.  Try seeing if you can write to /tmp.  If you can't look for other issues.  As a general rule blasting 777 permissions can lead to security holes.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the problem does not lie in folder ownership?

maybe chown is the right command to solve this problem

Comment: eric, good question...i did chown the folder to my plesk user and the group psacln...should that work?

Comment: im not sure what role your plesk user should play but just remember that it is the web server which runs the mkdir command, not the end user browser. If you're using apache i think apache creates a user with that name

Comment: good point, ill check that...so maybe the user shoudl actually be "apache".